# Financial number format

Tags: output-formatting

How can I change this function:

```
nFormat=NumberForm[#,{\[Infinity],2},NumberPoint->",",NumberSeparator->".",DigitBlock->3,ExponentStep->10]&;
```

So when I use it like:

```
nFormat/@{10.01,10.1,0.1}//Column
```

> 10,01
>
> 10,10
>
> 1.000.000.000,00*10^(-10)

The last number `1.000.000.000,00*10^(-10)` get the format equals to `0.10`?

Comment: Setting `ExponentStep` to 2 gives a result You want, but I'm not sure if it is what You're looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See last paragraph in Scope:-

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExponentFunction.html

```
nFormat = NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 2},
    NumberPoint -> ",", NumberSeparator -> ".", DigitBlock -> 3, 
    ExponentFunction -> (Null &)] &;
```

Comment: Excellent! It's what I need. tks